# Pinescript - Convert Zigzag indicator from Pine V3 to V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I have the problem that I want to convert an indicator from version 3 to 5. That's all possible. Only the plot of the line is displayed incorrectly. No idea why. I have tried several times but the line in version 5 is not shown on the chart as ZigZag. See pictures

[Screen Version 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqqOI.jpg)

[Screen Version 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btQJK.jpg)

**Script Pinecript V3**

```
//@version=3

study("ZigZag", overlay=true)

ZZPercent = input(0.5, title="Minimum % Change", type=float)

trend = 0
trend := na(trend[1]) ? 1 : trend[1]
LL = 0.0
LL := na(LL[1]) ? low : LL[1]
HH = 0.0
HH := na(HH[1]) ? high : HH[1]

PivotChg = ZZPercent * 0.01
zigzag = na

if (trend > 0)       // trend is up, look for new swing low
    if (high >= HH)  // new higher high detected
        HH := high
    else
        if (low < HH * (1 - PivotChg))
            zigzag := high[1]
            trend := -1
            LL := low
else                 // trend is down, look for new swing high
    if (low <= LL)   // new lower low detected
        LL := low
    else
        if (high > LL * (1 + PivotChg))
            zigzag := low[1]
            trend := 1
            HH := high

plot(zigzag, linewidth=2, offset=-1)
```

**Script Pinecript V5**

```
//@version=5 
ZZPercent = input.float(0.45, title="Minimum % Change")

trend = 0
trend := na(trend[1]) ? 1 : trend[1]
LL = 0.0
LL := na(LL[1]) ? low : LL[1]
HH = 0.0
HH := na(HH[1]) ? high : HH[1]

PivotChg = ZZPercent * 0.01
var float zigzag = na

if (trend > 0)       // trend is up, look for new swing low
    if (high >= HH)  // new higher high detected
        HH := high
    else
        if (low < HH * (1 - PivotChg))
            zigzag := high[1]
            trend := -1
            LL := low
else                 // trend is down, look for new swing high
    if (low <= LL)   // new lower low detected
        LL := low
    else
        if (high > LL * (1 + PivotChg))
            zigzag := low[1]
            trend := 1
            HH := high

plot(zigzag, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line, offset=-1)  //
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in the `v5` version, you have added the `var` keyword to your `zigzag` variable. When you define it with the `var` keyword, it will keep its value between each execution.

In the `v3` version, the `zigzag` value is `na` when there is no pivot. In your version, if there is no pivot, the `zigzag` value will be the last pivot price.

Simply remove the `var` keyword and it is a 1:1 match.

```
float zigzag = na
```